# How can I delete Siri App Suggestions in iOS 10.1?

Tags: iphone, applications, siri, ios

[image]

How can I remove Siri App Suggestions in iOS 10.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Disable Siri app suggestions in iOS 10](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7664740?start=0&tstart=0)

> You can disable Siri App suggestions by pulling the notification
>   center down (where the Siri App suggestions is located) go all the way
>   down and there you find a round button with edit on it. A screen will
>   appear where you will have full control over what you want in your
>   notification center.